# How to calculate next birthday given a date of birth?

Tags: postgresql

Given this schema in a Postgres database:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    birth_date date,
);
```

How would I query the table to get the date of each person's *next* birthday after today?

For example if Bob's `birth_date` is 2000-06-01 then his next birthday would be 2016-06-01.

Note: I'm not looking for the `birth_date` + a pre-defined `interval` but rather the next anniversary of a person's birth.

I've written the equivalent in Python:

```
def next_birthday(self):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    next_birthday = self.birth_date.replace(year=today.year)
    if next_birthday < today:
        next_birthday = next_birthday.replace(year=today.year + 1)
    return next_birthday
```

However I'd like to see if Postgres can do this in a more performant way.

Comment: @PetrHejda – that answer selects birthdays in a given date range (1 week from today). I'm looking to get the next anniversary of each person's birthday.

Comment: @Shanimal – that answer filters rows, whereas I'm looking to calculate the next upcoming birthday for each person.

Comment: What about Feb 29, what should it return? If there is no Feb 29 next year, should it return Feb 28, Mar 1, or the next Feb 29?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select birth_date,
       cast(birth_date + ((extract(year from age(birth_date)) + 1) * interval '1' year) as date) as next_birthday
from person
where name = 'Bob'
```

The expression `(extract(year from age(birth_date)) + 1) * interval '1' year` calculates the age at the next birthday in (complete) years. When adding that to the date of birth, this gives the next birthday.

The cast is necessary to get a real `date` back, because `date + interval` returns a timestamp (including a time).

If you remove the `where` condition, you'll get all "next" birthdays.

You can also get a list of the upcoming birthdays in e.g. the next 30 days using something like this:

```
select next_birthday,
       next_birthday - current_date as days_until_next
from (
  select birth_date,
         cast(birth_date + ((extract(year from age(birth_date)) + 1) * interval '1' year) as date) as next_birthday
  from person
) as upcoming
where upcoming.next_birthday <= current_date + 30
order by next_birthday;
```

Comment: Brilliant :) How would you extend/change this query so it would not only give you a list of the next birthdays, but also the birthdays in 2, 3, 4.. years?
In this case i would do `LIMIT 50`.. thanks in advance!

Comment: The second query is the best solution for the upcoming birthday problem I found so far. The only issue that it has: it does not capture todays birthdays, but only the ones from tomorrow on.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    birth_date
    +
    cast(
        date_part('year', current_date)
        -
        date_part('year', birth_date)
        +
        CASE
            WHEN
                date_part('month', birth_date) <
                        date_part('month', current_date)
                OR (
                    date_part('month', birth_date) =
                            date_part('month', current_date)
                    AND
                    date_part('day', birth_date) <
                            date_part('day', current_date)
                )
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END || ' year' as interval)
FROM person;
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT date birth_date + interval '1 year' as next_birthday
from person;

Comment: This only gives the person's first birthday but I realise my question is ambiguous on that point and will update!