# MySQL get next instance of a date of birth / birthday

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I am trying to find the next instance of a date in MySQL based on a DOB - for example, if the DOB is 1975-12-20 and we are running it today then the next birthday is 2020-12-20.

Likewise if the DOB is 1975-12-19 then the next birthday is 2020-12-19 but if the DOB is 1975-12-21 then the next birthday is 2019-12-21.

I can do this in PHP by exploding the date and replacing the year but I want to try and do it in MySQL as it will be quicker to run etc

DOB is a date field 0000-00-00

I found [How to calculate next birthday given a date of birth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081182/how-to-calculate-next-birthday-given-a-date-of-birth) for postgressql which I thought would work but it is using a function called age which doesnt seem to work in MySQL

Comment: What is the type of DOB ?

Comment: This could help you replace the age function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19522129/4461980 and then it's basically the same query as in the question you linked to

Comment: What should be the result if DOB is `2000-02-29` ?

Comment: Also note that doing this in mysql isn't necessarily faster, have you benchmarked it? Don't forget that a few microseconds in enhanced speed might not outweigh the benefits of easy maintainability you'd get from doing it in the backend

Comment: I doubt it will be quicker.

Comment: I cannot benchmark yet as I do not have the MySQL version working yet but I will

Comment: 29th Feb is an interesting one - some I assume will treat 28 Feb as their birthday and some 1st March in non leap years so I dont' think there is a perfect answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do date arithmetic as follows:

```
dob
+ interval (
    year(curdate()) 
    - year(dob) 
    + (dayofyear(curdate()) > dayofyear(dob))
) year
```

Basically, this takes the differences between the current date and the year of birth, and adds 1 if the birthday of the current year is in the past. This gives you the number of years to add to the dob to get the next birthday.

When it comes to February 29th, the above expression would return February 28th on non-leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Created a fiddle with sample data and query to get the next birthday date. Sharing below is query and sql fiddle link:

```
select *, 
IF(month(dob) = month(now()) AND day(dob) > day(now()), concat(Year(now()),'-',month(dob),'-',day(dob)) ,concat(Year(now())+1,'-',month(dob),'-',day(dob))) as nextBirthDay
from TableName
```

Sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/033ad4/18

Comment: This does work for me - one thing is that the dates come back as 2020-1-1 for example. Can they come back as 2020-01-01?

Comment: you can do that, but again it will be very difficult to manage in future. I will suggest do it in php, it will be single liner.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way. For the current year.

```
select DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, dob, now()) + (dayofyear(dob) > dayofyear(now())) YEAR) as result
```

In sandbox
https://paiza.io/projects/iCDmx0RP1jck56xXzGu2Jw?language=mysql